# How can I delete accidentally uploaded attachment files to GitHub? (about comment attachments, not repository files)

Tags: github

GitHub has nice feature that you can attach files to issue comments.

But is there any way to undo attaching unwanted file?

Even if comment is never submitted the file stays there forever, see for example https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/899988/146889867-edb59e9a-5709-4c17-b6d5-b0c863bc5f9e.png

It is even worse with .ods files where randomly generated part is much shorter.

How can I trigger deletion of such accidentally uploaded files if I have link to them?

Comment: Even worse, if you paste into a file in a private repository, the generated image link is publicly accessible!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're the uploader of the image, which has an URL in this format `https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/123456/123456789-abcdefgh-1234-abcd-1234-1234abcd5678.png`, you can now make use of the virtual agent to remove the image: https://support.github.com/?q=remove+image+attachment

Click on the button "Remove uploaded images with our Virtual Agent".

[image: Remove uploaded images with GitHub Virtual Agent]

If you're trying to delete an uploaded file with an URL in this format `https://github.com/github/linguist/files/1/example.docx`, use this link instead: https://support.github.com/?q=remove+file+attachment

The deletion is not instant, but took less than a day.

Comment: I just tested it with https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/899988/146889867-edb59e9a-5709-4c17-b6d5-b0c863bc5f9e.png - lets see how it will go

Comment: Can I batch delete attachments? Maybe with the Attachment API?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that contacting support is the only viable chance to fix such issues ( https://support.github.com/contact ).